# PostgreSql Queries treats Int as string datatypes

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, querying

I store the following rows in my table ('DataScreen') under a JSONB column ('Results')

```
{"Id":11,"Product":"Google Chrome","Handle":3091,"Description":"Google Chrome"}
{"Id":111,"Product":"Microsoft Sql","Handle":3092,"Description":"Microsoft Sql"}
{"Id":22,"Product":"Microsoft OneNote","Handle":3093,"Description":"Microsoft OneNote"}
{"Id":222,"Product":"Microsoft OneDrive","Handle":3094,"Description":"Microsoft OneDrive"}
```

Here, In this JSON objects "Id" amd "Handle" are integer properties and other being string properties.

When I query my table like below

```
Select Results->>'Id'  From DataScreen  
order by Results->>'Id' ASC
```

I get the improper results because PostgreSql treats everything as a text column and hence does the ordering according to the text, and not as integer.
Hence it gives the result as

```
11,111,22,222
```

instead of

```
11,22,111,222.
```

I don't want to use explicit casting to retrieve like below

```
Select Results->>'Id'  From DataScreen order by CAST(Results->>'Id' AS INT)  ASC
```

because I will not be sure of the datatype of the column due to the fact that JSON structure will be dynamic and the keys and values may change next time. and Hence could happen the same with another JSON that has Integer and string keys.

I want something so that Integers in Json structure of JSONB column are treated as integers only and not as texts (string).

How do I write my query so that Id And Handle are retrieved as Integer Values and not as strings , without explicit casting?

Comment: Well, in JSON everything _is_ a text. Casting **is** your only option. If you need strongly typed columns, normalize and don't use JSON

Answer (score 0):

I think your assumtions about the `id` field don't make sense. You said,

> (a) Either `id` contains integers only or
>
> (b) it contains strings and integers.

I'd say,

> If (a) then numerical ordering is correct.
>
> If (b) then lexical ordering is correct.

But if (a) for some time and then (b) then the correct order changes, too. And *that* doesn't make sense. Imagine:

For the current database you expect the order `11,22,111,222`. Then you add a row

```
{"Id":"aa","Product":"Microsoft OneDrive","Handle":3095,"Description":"Microsoft OneDrive"}
```

and suddenly the *correct* order of the other rows changes to `11,111,22,222,aa`. `That` sudden change is what bothers me.

So I would either expect a lexical ordering ab intio, or restrict my `id` field to integers and use explicit casting.

Every other option I can think of is just not practical. You could, for example, create a custom `<` and `>` implementation for your `id` field which results in `11,111,22,222,aa`. ("Order all integers by numerical value and all strings by lexical order and put all integers before the strings").

But that is a lot of work (it involves a custom data type, a custom cast function and a custom operator function) and yields some counterintuitive results, e.g. `11,111,22,222,0a,1a,2a,aa` (note the position of `0a` and so on. They come after `222`).

Hope, that helps ;)

Comment: No, the Id field always has integers and not alphanumeric

Comment: You said: "I will not be sure of the datatype of the column due to the fact that JSON structure will be dynamic and the keys and values may change next time. and Hence could happen the same with another JSON that has Integer and string keys."

Comment: Yes, I meant that the JSON output mayl no longer be the same set of keys and values. It may be a different set of JSON key and Value pairs. But if it is "Id" or "Handle" keys (and may be others), it has got to be Integers. Likewise, there could be many set of keys which have got integer values. But I don't want to be casting it explicitly because I am not sure what JSON output will be produced next time, and which all keys will be integers and which not.

Comment: @puneet: if you are sure that `Id` **always** contains integers, then why isn't casting an option?

Answer (score 0):

If `Id` always integer you can cast it in select part and just use `ORDER BY 1`:

```
select (Results->>'Id')::int  From DataScreen order by 1  ASC
```